# what is the best way to modify a particular line of a csv file without erasing everything?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file open with notepad :

[image]

I want to modify my csv to replace line 4 with 'Temperature Level Wave Degre':

[image]
My code :

```
                with open(file.csv, 'w') as m:
                content = m.readlines()
                line_4 = (content[3])

                line_4.replace(line_4, 'Temperature Level Wave Degre')
```

My csv is empty!

What is the best way to modify a particular line of a csv file without erasing everything ?
The most efficient code?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need pandas for that, actually I wouldn't even use python. I would probably use `awk` in command line: `awk 'NR==4 {$0="Temperature Level Wave Degre"} { print }' filename.csv> new_file.csv`

Comment: I am not using pandas, but it can be a solution? I want to automate this action and therefore I want to do it in python.

Comment: Please add the code in plain text, I recomend you to read this thread: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using python, however as I mentioned in my comment, there are likely more efficient command line tools (I would use `awk`)

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()                        # read lines and store in list
    lines[3] = 'Temperature Level Wave Degre\n'  # change line 4, don't forget to add a newline
    f.seek(0)                                    # come back to beginning of file
    f.writelines(lines)                          # write the new lines
    f.truncate()                                 # ensure we don't keep old stuff from the previous file
```